# Erroneous color function for ContourPlot when the function has a small positive region and the PlotRange is specified manually

Tags: plotting, bugs, color

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Consider this `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[.05 - .005 (x^2 + y^2), {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}, 
 PlotRange -> {-2, 2},
 Contours -> 20,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Clearly the color bar is wrong, assigning the region with the highest value to have the same color as the lowest value.

This problem goes away if you set the `PlotRange-> All` option, or if you set `PlotRange-> {-2,x}` where `x` is any number lower than 0.31 (e.g. 0.309999).

What is causing this behavior?  Is it a bug?

Comment: You haven't posted the code that produces the plot.

Comment: @eli-morris, without the values of `dataSlice3Adj` we can't really try to reproduce the plot.  What happens when you replace `PlotRange -> {-2, 2}` with `PlotRange -> All` and replace `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All]` with `PlotLegends -> Automatic`?

Comment: Sorry. I just put in all the data, although, it's a little in the wrong order for evaluation. I guess I was thinking that the Mathematica answer was so off, it *might* be wrong in a way that someone could catch on to it as is.  I can't image really any plot where both -1.5 and 0 would be basically the same color in the plot with a bunch of different colors in between Just weird, imho. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EliMorris, it is almost letting me plot, but is missing definitions for `AdjustOriginX`, `CenterY`, and `NormalizeValues`.    Basically, if we can get it so we can reproduce the problem you are having, we can see why it's doing that.  But if we can't, then it's pretty hard to help

Comment: The problem can be reproduced using e.g. `0.05 - 0.005 (x^2 + y^2)` as the function to be plotted.

Comment: Thanks for reframing the problem. I got totally bogged down with it last night and didn't do a very good job of explaining it. The thing is I'm making several similar plots and they all need to have the same contour range and intervals. Otherwise, the plots are not comparable. This has to be a bug. It's so strange...

Comment: It is definitely buggy behavior, but I think we can come up with a workaround.  If you need to plot several contour plots on the same scale I think the answer is to use a custom `ColorFunction` and turn `ColorFunctionScaling` off.  I am out of the office for the day, but I can post this in the morning.

Comment: I think this works. It doesn't look quite the same because if uses a different ColorFunction. I'm not sure what the default ColorFunction is named. `ContourPlot[.05 - .005 (x^2 + y^2), {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}, 
    PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {-2.0, 2.0}}]), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False] `

Comment: @EliMorris, it has the truly memorable name of "M10DefaultDensityGradient".  Also, I think you have to go one step further to make the colorbar in the legend show the full color range, see my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I certainly think this is a bug, but you can get around it by using a custom `ColorFunction`, turning off `ColorFunctionScaling`, manually setting the range of the legend, and finally by manually setting the contour levels.  This is the only way to ensure that you can compare multiple contour or density plots (I also use this method when I am trying to make an animation, so the color scale and contour levels can't change between frames.

```
colorfunc = ColorData[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-2.0, 2.0}}];
contours = Subdivide[-2.0, 2.0, 20];
ContourPlot[#, {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12},
   PlotRange -> {-2, 2},
   Contours -> contours,
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colorfunc, {-2, 2}}],
   ColorFunction -> colorfunc,
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {.05 - .005 (x^2 + y^2), 
  1.8 - .015 (x^2 + y^2), .01 (x^2 + y^2 - x y)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I reported this problem to Wolfram and they confirmed that it is indeed a bug and that they have forwarded the problem to the development team so they can fix it.